# What do you call a matrix that has at most one value in each row and each column?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology

Is there a linear algebra terminology for matrices that are limited to at most one value in each row and column?

For example:
This counts:

> $\pmatrix{0& 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0& 1& 0& 0 \\ 0& 0& 0& 1 \\ 1&0&0&0}$

While this is not:

> $\pmatrix{1& 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0& 1& 1& 1 \\ 1& 0& 0& 1 \\ 1&0&0&0}$

Thanks very much!

Comment: Those having only a one in each row and cloumn are called permutation matrices.

Comment: To clarify, you say "*at* **most**" one value, so a matrix like $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ would be okay?

Comment: You mean "at most one **nonzero** value" apparently.   I don't know if there's a name for them, but they can be characterized as those matrices of the form $PD$ where $P$ is a permutation matrix and $D$ is a diagonal matrix (or $DP$, but then with a different $D$).

Comment: @JMoravitz Your matrix having a row of zeros is not a permutation matrix. A lermutation matrix is obtained by swapping rows of the identity matrix.

Comment: @Any of course it isn't, I never said that it should be a permutation matrix (*nor a lermutation matrix for that matter*).  I was asking the OP that question, not Crostul.

Comment: Some possibilities are permutation, projection, scaling.

Comment: @Any: Projection matrices would typically not have this property.

Comment: @ Jonas Meyer You are right of course.

Comment: In vector lattice terminology, these are precisely the matrices that preserve disjointness.

Answer (score 3):

[Monomial](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Monomial_matrix) or [generalized permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_permutation_matrix) matrix are names, at least if there's exactly one nonzero entry in each row and column.

Googling `"at most one nonzero entry in each"` led to a reference to "monomial," and googling `"monomial matrix"` then led to the above references.

One of the other references appearing in the original search uses the term "monomial" with the "at most" rather than "exactly", in some book called [*Groups and computation II*](https://books.google.com/books?id=lyL8Ui36FKsC&pg=PA212).

These would be the matrices that have the form $PD$ or $DP$ with $P$ a permutation matrix and $D$ diagonal.